# How optimize time while sign pdf with iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextsharp 5.5.13.0 to sign pdf files with a smart card (X509Certificate2) in a C # project. The process of stamping the signature is fine, but the time it takes to sign is much more than in an earlier version that was had for this process (iTextsharp 4.1.2.0).

Previously, it took no more than 10 seconds between the certificate was selected and the signature process finished, now it takes more than double.

This is the code where the pdf is signed. I also attach an image of the time it takes to sign. There is something I can do to reduce the time of signing?

```
public static void SignHashed(string Source, string Target, X509Certificate2 Certificate, string Reason, string Location, bool AddTimeStamp, string strTSA)
    {
        X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
        X509Certificate[] objChain = new X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData) };

        IList<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
        crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(objChain));

        PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(Source);
        PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create), '\0', null, true);

        int pageNumber = objReader.NumberOfPages;

        ITSAClient tsaClient = null;
        IOcspClient ocspClient = null;
        if (AddTimeStamp)
        {
            OcspVerifier ocspVerifier = new OcspVerifier(null, null);
            ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
            tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(strTSA);
        }

        PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signatureAppearance.Reason = Reason;
        signatureAppearance.Location = Location;
        signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = true;
        signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION;
        signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 10, 200, 66), pageNumber, null);

        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(Certificate, "SHA-1");

        // this process take to much time
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, objChain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        if (objReader != null)
        {
            objReader.Close();
        }
        if (objStamper != null)
        {
            objStamper.Close();
        }
    }
```

[image: Time MakeSignature process]

Comment: I have heard somewhere, crypto-algorithm are slow by design (form of prevention against brutal force)

Comment: Were your tests done with `AddTimeStamp == true` or `== false`? Have you tested without CRL clients?